# Why is this regex replace statement failing to do anything?

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

Below is a tiny method to basically replace the word "Stack" with ".png" in a string. So something called "Grid01Stack" would return as "Grid01.png" however the operation doesn't do anything at all, the string remains the same. What is going wrong? Here is the code:

```
private string GetUriFromName(string GridName)
    {            
        string result = Regex.Replace(GridName, @"\bStack\b", ".png");
        return (@"Resources/Images/"+result);
    }
```

Comment: The first word boundary `\b` does not match between `1S`

Comment: There isn't a word boundary between `1` and `S`. `1` and `S` are both word characters.

Comment: `\bStack\b` -> `Stack\b`

Comment: You don't need Regex for that. `GridName.Replace("Stack", ".png")` is enough

Comment: If you want to check if the string ends with `"Stack"`, you can use this pattern : `"Stack$"`

Comment: Do not use word boundaries if you do not plan to match whole words. Just use `string result = GridName.Replace(@"Stack", ".png");` in this case. If you plan to match it at the end, then you may use `"Stack$"` regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can simply do, per Yuri and Cid's suggestions:

```
GridName.Replace("Stack",".png")
```

This is not the best option if the word 'Stack' will ever appear more than once in the string, as it will replace all instances. So, for example, `"Stack01Stack"` will become `".png01.png"`. As you are trying to form a good filename, you really only want to replace the last occurence of "Stack" with ".png", and only if it at the end of the string. Therefore, using "Stack\b" as the comments suggested could end up messing with valid filenames as well, if Stack shows up multiple times. For instance, using that Regex `"GridStack-01Stack"` will become `"Grid.png-01.png"`

This is all based on speculation of what these strings *might* be, so this solution might not be necessary, but I'd recommend the following Regex, which will only change the word Stack if it occurs at the end of the string:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(GridName, "Stack$", ".png");
```

Answer (score 1):

**\b**Stack**\b** - is looking for the whole word 'Stack' with spaces, tab, line break, etc before and after word.

You just need the **String.Replace** for you case.

Answer (score 1):

• String replace: `string x = "Grid01Stack".Replace("Stack", ".png");`

• Regex: `string x = Regex.Replace("Grid01Stack", "[Ss]tack$", ".png");`
The regex will search for `Stack` or `stack` which are always in the end of the string.